# Is there any way to debug/log variables in validator?

Tags: plutus

As a newbie in Plutus and Haskell, I write code by printing/logging variables to see their value, which is the only reason why I managed to write Contract, off-chain Plutus part.
My question is, are there any possible ways (even hacky ones, doesn't matter), to inspect variable value in on-chain, validator Plutus part.

I am aware of trace, traceIfFalse, etc. All of the functions can be found here:
https://playground.plutus.iohkdev.io/doc/haddock/plutus-tx/html/PlutusTx-Trace.html
But it doesn't help, as you can't inspect variables.

This enhancement seems to be dead:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus/issues/3164
Searched a lot of sources and found nothing useful. I am aware why it's difficult (BuiltInString, absence of Show), only asking for possible solutions/tricks/hacks and not for explanation why it's impossible.

This question is related:
[Logging in validator](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/logging-in-validator?rq=1)

Thanks

EDIT:

let's image I have a validator:

```
mkValidator :: Order -> Order -> OrderAction -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator o oDatum act ctx = True
```

how can I print the value of for example ctx (ScriptContext), or oDatum, then executing the whole script with Emulator, so that whole script compiles and I can see ctx Value somewhere in EmulatorTrace (or any other way)?

I mean something like this:

```
mkValidator o oDatum act ctx = trace "test" ctx && True
```

Comment: Why is impossible to inspect variables with `trace`? Could you include specific examples of what you're trying to do?

Comment: let's image I have a validator: 
mkValidator :: Order -> Order -> OrderAction -> ScriptContext -> Bool
mkValidator o oDatum act ctx = True.

how can I print the value of for example ctx (ScriptContext), or oDatum, then executing the whole script with Emulator, so that whole script compiles and I can see ctx Value somewhere in EmulatorTrace?

I mean something like this:
mkValidator o oDatum act ctx = trace "test" ctx && True

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to work around this yet. Validation is a side effect free function (a pure function) so it can't write to any log.

What I do is create a debug endpoint in my contract log info there

So I will have something like this

```
debug :: AsContractError e => () -> Contract w Schema e ()
debug _ = do
        utxos <- utxosAt address
        Contract.logInfo @String $ show utxos
        Contract.logInfo @String $ show (length utxos)
        wallet1Utxos <- utxosAt . walletAddress $ knownWallet 2
        Contract.logInfo @String $ show wallet1Utxos
        wallet2Utxos <- utxosAt . walletAddress $ knownWallet 1
        Contract.logInfo @String $ "Utxos for wallet 2: " ++ show wallet2Utxos
```

And then use that in a EmulatorTrace()

```
mintAndTransfer :: EmulatorTrace ()
mintAndTransfer = do
        let tn = "USDC"
        h1 <- activateContractWallet (knownWallet 1) (endpoints @ContractError)
        callEndpoint @"mint" h1 $ MintParams
                { mintParamsTokenName = tn
                , mintParamsAmount = 100 }
        void $ waitNSlots 1
        callEndpoint @"mint" h1 $ MintParams
                { mintParamsTokenName = tn
                , mintParamsAmount = 200 }
        void $ waitNSlots 1
        callEndpoint @"transferToWallet" h1 $ TransferToWalletParams
                { tpTo = walletPubKeyHash $ knownWallet 2
                , tpAmount = 50
                , tpTokenName = tn }
        void $ waitNSlots 1
        callEndpoint @"debug" h1 ()
        void $ waitNSlots 1
```

Not ideal I know but it helps sometime.

Answer (score 2):

There is a recent update regarding the error message from validator onchain here https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/releases
If you update your cardano-node to version 1.31.0, you will be able to see log message from traceIfFalse. Something like

```
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Script debugging logs: UTxO not consumed
```

Like @Calin answered, you can always run any test with the Emulator Trace, which gives you where it fails onchain.

Comment: It is still just a pre-prepared string logging, not variable logging though

Comment: Yes, that's right, but at least it gets improved and now while testing on testnet/mainnet we at least know which condition doesn't meet.